# {fmt}: Compile-time string format check doesn't work

Tags: c++, g++, fmt

I am trying to get the format string check on compile time working with fmt 5.3.0 (headers only).

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
```

```cpp
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#define FMT_STRING_ALIAS 1

#include <fmt/format.h>

int main(){
  std::string s = format(fmt("{2}"), 42);
  return 0;
}
```

`$ g++ -I../include -std=c++11 test.cpp`
...nothing

According to the fmt readme, this should produce an error (https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compile time checking requires sufficient constexpr support. With [g++ 5.4 and c++ 11](https://godbolt.org/z/f0TJWm) there will not be a compile time check, but with [g++ 6.1 and c++ 14](https://godbolt.org/z/n9iUuy) there will be. See also the definition of [FMT_USE_CONSTEXPR](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/include/fmt/core.h#L58).

Comment: Thanks!
This worked:
Install g++-6: https://gist.github.com/zuyu/7d5682a5c75282c596449758d21db5ed
`g++-6 -I../include -std=c++14 test.cpp`:

`context_.on_error("argument index out of range");`